# Finding possible values for exponential identity without logarithms

Tags: exponential-function

So I was teaching a student high school math and I came upon this problem:

Assuming one has more than oce solution for x, for the equation

$4^{ax} = 8.b^{x}$, find all possible solution of $a, b$.

Point is I can find the answer using trial and error, how can I *algebraically* solve it?

Thanks.

P.S. Using logarithms isn't allowed, only exponents!

Comment: is this $$4^{ax}=8\cdot b^x$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if so we have $$2ax\ln(2)=3\ln(2)+x\ln(b)$$ and then:
$$x(2a\ln(2)-\ln(3))=3\ln(2))$$ thus we get
$$x=\frac{3\ln(2)}{2a\ln(2)-\ln(3)}$$ for $$b>0,2a\ln(2)-\ln(3)\ne 0$$

Comment: As I said this problem features in the exponent section, using logarithms isn't allowed!

Comment: i think in this method is to find the variable $x$ impossible

Comment: I thought the same, but the textbook specifically asks the question :(

Comment: maybe there is a typo in your textbook